# What is the best event to be fired when adding and deleting a free product in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, addtocart, delete

I want to add product Y to cart with product X and want to delete product Y when product X is deleted.(both should be worked automatically). For this purpose what will be the best event to be fired??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For add product you can use event

```
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add
```

For remove item from checkout cart best event to use is

```
sales_quote_remove_item
```

Thanks.